# Plotting phase diagram for the velocity vs position graph. Interpolation as a possible solution?

Tags: pgfplots

I need to plot a few graphs. First is of the function

\begin{equation}
x(t)= -e^{ -0.1  t} \cos \left(  0.995 t \right)
\end{equation}

and of $\dot{x}$ (time derivative function)

\begin{equation}
    \dot{x}(t)= e^{-0.1  t}\left[(0.1 ) \cos \left( 0.995 t \right)+ ( 0.995 )\sin ( 0.995 t )\right] .
\end{equation}

I have so far made their individual plots by doing the following

```
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
        \caption{ The plots of the position and speed versus time (underdamped oscillator).}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.9]
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = {$t$, $ \left[\text{s} \right]$},
    %ylabel = {$a(t)$, $ \left[\text{m/s}^2 \right]$},
    grid=major,
    ymin=-1,
    ymax=1,
]
\addplot [
    domain=0:60, 
     samples=300, 
    color=YellowGreen, 
    thick,
]
{2.71828^(-0.1*x)*cos(deg(0.995*x-3.1415))};
\addlegendentry{\tiny $ x(t)$, , $ \left[\text{cm} \right]$}
\addplot [
    domain=0:60,
     samples=300,
    color=TealBlue,
     thick,
    ]
    {-2.71828^(-0.1*x)*((0.1*cos(deg(0.995*x-3.1415))+0.995*sin(deg(0.995*x-3.1415))) };
\addlegendentry{\tiny $  \dot{x}(t)$,  $ \left[\text{cm/s} \right]$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

with the resulting graph

[image]

**What remains a problem: question 1.** The second plot I need is the phase diagram, i.e. $\dot{x}(t)$ vs $x(t)$ plot, which I am not sure how to construct. I was thinking sampling/point-harvesting of the function $x(t)$ and $\dot{x}(t)$ to then use those points for interpolation-construction of the phase diagram might be somehow implemented? However, I could not find a lot of information about these kinds of things on latex forums. My boyfriend has made his graphs with python, so I know the phase diagram must look like the following

[image]

But I was hoping to there is some way of making the graphs using latex alone. Any ideas?

**What remains a problem: question 2.** I also was wondering if there is any way of determining how many times does the system cross the $x=0$ line before the amplitude falls below $10^{-2}$ of its maximum value, but if it is possible to do only using latex commands to output this number.

Comment: I agree. However since it’s so specific to the discipline I thought people here would be more knowledgeable to help with my issue.

Comment: We can help you with any concepts on physics regarding your analysis and graphs, however we will not be the right people to ask about LaTeX graphing even if your graphs are somehow related to physics.